# using f1 score sklearn in pytorch ignite custom metric

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-ignite

I would like to use the f1_score of sklearn in a custom metric of PyTorch-ignite.
I couldn't find a good solution. although on the official website of PyTorch-ignite, there is a solution of

```
    precision = Precision(average=False)
    recall = Recall(average=False)
    F1 = Fbeta(beta=1.0, average=False, precision=precision, recall=recall)
```

, if you need to have an f1 score micro/macro/weighted, you can not use this example.

how can I use a custom metric with the sklearn library?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is first create a custom metric:

```py
import torch
from ignite.metrics import Metric
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score


class F1Score(Metric):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.f1 = 0
        self.count = 0
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, output):
        y_pred, y = output[0].detach(), output[1].detach()

        _, predicted = torch.max(y_pred, 1)
        f = f1_score(y.cpu(), predicted.cpu(), average='micro')
        self.f1 += f
        self.count += 1

    def reset(self):
        self.f1 = 0
        self.count = 0
        super(F1Score, self).reset()

    def compute(self):
        return self.f1 / self.count
```

then you can use it in `create_supervised_evaluator` or `create_supervised_trainer` as :

```py
import logging

import torch
from ignite.engine import Events
from ignite.engine import create_supervised_evaluator
from ignite.metrics import Accuracy, Fbeta
from ignite.metrics.precision import Precision
from ignite.metrics.recall import Recall

from metrics.f1score import F1Score


def inference(
        cfg,
        model,
        val_loader
):
    device = cfg.MODEL.DEVICE

    logger = logging.getLogger("template_model.inference")
    logger.info("Start inferencing")

    precision = Precision(average=False)
    recall = Recall(average=False)
    F1 = Fbeta(beta=1.0, average=False, precision=precision, recall=recall)
    metrics = {'accuracy': Accuracy(),
               'precision': precision,
               'recall': recall,
               'custom': F1Score(),
               'f1': F1}
    evaluator = create_supervised_evaluator(model,
                                            metrics=metrics,
                                            device=device)

    # adding handlers using `evaluator.on` decorator API
    @evaluator.on(Events.EPOCH_COMPLETED)
    def print_validation_results(engine):
        metrics = evaluator.state.metrics
        metrics = evaluator.state.metrics

        _avg_accuracy = metrics['accuracy']

        _precision = metrics['precision']
        _precision = torch.mean(_precision)

        _recall = metrics['recall']
        _recall = torch.mean(_recall)

        _f1 = metrics['f1']
        _f1 = torch.mean(_f1)

        _custom = metrics['custom']
        logger.info(
            "Test Results - Epoch: {} Avg accuracy: {:.3f}, precision: {:.3f}, recall: {:.3f}, f1 score: {:.3f}, custom: {:.2f}".format(
                engine.state.epoch, _avg_accuracy, _precision, _recall, _f1, _custom))

    evaluator.run(val_loader)
```

the result is:

```
Test Results - Epoch: 1 Avg accuracy: 0.758, precision: 0.776, recall: 0.766, f1 score: 0.759, custom: 0.76
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use ignites Precision and Recall implementations as follows:

```
from ignite.metrics import Precision, Recall

precision = Precision(average=False)
recall = Recall(average=False)
F1 = (precision * recall * 2 / (precision + recall)).mean()
```

Then you add F1 to the metrics dictionary.